# Class applied to ul or to the wrapping div?

Tags: html, css, cross-browser, accessibility

Is there a difference beetwen #1 and #2? I'm thinking about cross browser compatibility and accessibility. Should I prefer one approach to the other or it doesn't make a difference?
Any link to articles on the subject is welcome.

```
<div class="tags">
<ul>
<li>tag 1</li>
<li>tag 2</li>
<li>tag 3</li>
</ul>
</div>


<ul class="tags">
<li>tag 1</li>
<li>tag 2</li>
<li>tag 3</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: You should try to keep your html as lean as possible which means avoiding unnecessary divs.  A div has no semantic meaning and should only be used if you need it.  In the above example with out any further context, you should go with option 2.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A div is an empty (semantically meaningless) element until you give it styles and content.  Since both divs and uls are both block-level elements by default, it seems like it's just adding extra code to use a wrapping div.  Unless you are trying to do something like, say, style the area around the ul, where you may want a wrapping div with its own styles applied.  Is there any particular purpose you have in mind that we may see?

Comment: Thanks. It's the list of tags that goes at the end of each blog post. They're already inside a <footer> tag and I don't need a particular style so I'll go with #2.

Answer (score 0):

In cases where I want to put different content in the container, like with AJAX insertings, I prefer option 1. Since both `div` and `ul` are block-level elements, adding an extra `div` container is overkill, unless you want to style the div (i.e. padding)